# frequently changing data in mysql and offset

Tags: mysql

I have a user database where the online status of the user is being stored and i will list the users who are online in a web page(sorted by their status, (online users first and offline users later) and then sorted by username). There will be many users and i planned to implement pagination using offset and limit...

Their status may change frequently and it is possible that the user on the first page may be repeatedly shown on the second page and other pages if more users login at that time when the user clicks on the second page...

Is there any way to avoid that? Please tell me some ideas

Answer (score 0):

What you could for example do is run a query every minute that stores this data in another table.
Then your online/offline page can show the data from that table.

It is still possible that an user sees another user 'twice', however now it only happens once per minute, instead of every second for example.

However, as far as I am aware, you cannot totally avoid this.